# The absolute difference between sum to infinity and sum to n terms

Tags: binomial-theorem

How do I work this out?

> The first three terms of a geometric series are $2$, $-\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{8}$. Find the least value of $n$ for which the sum of the first $n$ terms of this series differs from the sum to infinity by less than $10^{-5}$.

So, it will be:

$$
S_{\infty}-S_n > 0.00001 \\
1.6 - \frac{2\left(1 - \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n\right)}{1.25} > 0.00001
$$

But I get stuck at this point. How do I commence?

Comment: The difference simplifies $1.6-S_n$ simplifies to $(1.6)(-1/4)^n$.

Comment: It's that simplification I'm having trouble with :)

Comment: $\frac{2}{1.25}=1.6$. And you will want the absolute value, and you will want $\lt 0.00001$.

Comment: Using Andre Nicolas's comment, $1.6-1.6(1-(-\frac{1}{4})^n)=1.6(1-(1-(-\frac{1}{4})^n)=1.6(-\frac{1}{4})^n$, so you want to solve $1.6(\frac{1}{4})^n<.00001$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from André:

$$
1.6 - 1.6\left(1 - \left(-\frac{1}{4}^n\right)\right) < 0.00001 \\
1.6\left(\frac{1}{4}^n\right) < 0.00001 \\
\frac{1}{4}^n < 0.00000625 \\
n > \frac{\log 0.00000625}{\log 0.25} \\
n > 9
$$

Comment: I get that the log ratio is about $8.65$. That makes it $n\ge 9$. so the least $n$ is $9$.

Comment: A bit more directly, the tail is the sum of the infinite geometric series $ar^n+ar^{n+1}+\cdots$, which by the usual formula is $\frac{ar^n}{1-r}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an alternating series, you just need to find the first term where $|2(-\frac14)^n| < 10^{-5}$.

$$\begin{align}
\left|2\left(-\frac14\right)^n)\right| &< 10^{-5}\\
2\left(\frac14\right)^n &< 10^{-5}\\
\left(\frac14\right)^n &< \frac{1}{200000}\\
200000 & < 4^n\\
\end{align}$$

$4^8 = 16384$ and $4^9 = 262144$, so the sum of the terms through $2\left(-\frac14\right)^8$ is accurate to within $10^{-5}$.

Comment: Fixed, thanks.  Needless extension of comment to be largern than 15 characters.